# GitLab/LDAP turn off users automatic block in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, ldap

When a user is blocked in Active Directory, I want to ensure that the same user is not automatically blocked in GitLab at the same time. How can I prevent GitLab from blocking the user after an AD block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason people use LDAP with GitLab is so that all information for users is updated in LDAP and not in GitLab. Along with other user updates, blocking in LDAP is tied to user synchronization.

Therefore, the only way to turn off auto-blocking is to turn off user sync. In fact, you can't technically turn user sync off, but you can [adjust the cron schedule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/ldap_synchronization.html#adjust-ldap-user-sync-schedule) so that it only runs once a year.

Comment: Thank you for answering, @Arty-chan. Okay, regarding that, could you please guide me on how to enable auto-unlocking after a user is unblocked in Active Directory?

Comment: Second question: How can I search for their commits after being blocked from LDAP?

Comment: User sync should auto-unblock users who are unblocked or readded to AD.
You should be able to search for commits by user in UI or API. If you have any issues, I suggest posting a separate question on StackOverflow or the GitLab Forums.

Comment: When users are blocked on AD after synchronization in GitLab, they are also blocked there. As a result, I cannot search for any commits related to them. How can I search for all commits or other information associated with that user?

Comment: if you're an admin, you should still be able to search for any commits, but again, I suggest posting a separate question since how LDAP blocking works is a very different thing from search for commits on blocked users

Comment: My developers want to find out all about blocked users. Can they do that?

Comment: again, searching for types of users is not related to LDAP, so I recommend posting a separate question.

Comment: To unblock users use User.find_by(email: 'my.user@domain.com').update!(state: 'active')